# java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported IV length: 10 bytes. Only 12 bytes long IV supported

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hello Everyone I am working on Android Project and i have to save JWT token in my sharedprefrences so for that i use Android KeyStore System to encrypt the data and store it i found some code from Internet and i rewrite it its works fine here it is

```
  fun Key_Store(Apikey: String){
   val keyGenerator : KeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
        KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
        "AndroidKeyStore"
    )

    val keyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        "alias",
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
    )
        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
        .build()


    keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
    val  secretKey: SecretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey()

    val  cipher:Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

    val iv = cipher.getIV();
    val encryption = cipher.doFinal(Apikey.toByteArray())
    Log.e("Real", "is " + Apikey)
    Log.e("Encription", "is " + encryption)


    //decrypting
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);

    val secretKeyEntry = keyStore
        .getEntry("alias", null) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry

    val secretKey2 = secretKeyEntry.secretKey

    val cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")

    val spec = GCMParameterSpec(128, iv)
    cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey2, spec)

    val decodedData = cipher2.doFinal(encryption)
    val unencryptedString = String(decodedData)
    Log.e("UnEncription", "is " + unencryptedString)
}
```

this works fine its encript the data and also decryopt it but when i devide this function in two functions then its give error
**java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported IV length: 10 bytes. Only 12 bytes long IV supported**
and not works for me here it is

```
  private fun encryptedKey (KEY_NAME: String, value: String){
    val keyGenerator : KeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
        KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
        "AndroidKeyStore"
    )

     val keyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        "pryze",
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
    )
        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
        .build()


    keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
    val  secretKey: SecretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey()

    val  cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

    val iv = cipher.getIV();
    val encryption = cipher.doFinal(value.toByteArray())

    val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPrefs.edit()
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME+"EN", encryption.toString())
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME+"IV", iv.toString())
    editor.commit()
    Log.e("IV Top", "is " + iv)

}

private fun decryptKey (KEY_NAME: String): String?{

    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);

    val secretKeyEntry = keyStore
        .getEntry("pryze", null) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry

    val secretKey2 = secretKeyEntry.secretKey

    val cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")

    val spec = GCMParameterSpec(128, sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_NAME+"IV", null)?.toByteArray())
    cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey2, spec)


    val decodedData = cipher2.doFinal(sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_NAME+"EN", null)?.toByteArray())
    val unencryptedString = String(decodedData)
    Log.e("UnEncription", "is " + unencryptedString)

    return unencryptedString
}
```

Comment: In your "full" version you run the decryption with the IV in binary form [directly taken from encryption] but your "split" functions save and read the IV from sharedPrefs. You save the binary IV as string but the string format is not suitable for binary data [think of x00 - it is not printable as string]. So as a solution you should encode your binary data e.g. with Base64 and Decode it for decryption.

Comment: I also use Base64 encoding but again there comes error but that error was different from this one

Comment: Kindly edit your question and add debug information of the "iv" value on your full version and the encrypt+decrypt version (in hex- or base64 encoding) to see what data you are using - without this information it's hard to tell where the error is.

Comment: `Cipher#doFinal()` and `Cipher#getIV()` return a `ByteArray`. `toString()` provides the object ID (e.g. something like _[B@ce660c3_), not the content. This is the reason for the exception. Instead, as recommended in Michael Fehr's comment, you should Base64 encode ciphertext and IV when encrypting and Base64 decode when decrypting. Do not use a charset encoding (like UTF8) as this corrupts the data. Runs fine with this change on my machine.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Michael Fehr`s and Mr Topaco for your response yes you both are right Base64 encryption is work fine now actually what i do first i only encrypt the VI and not not encrypt the encryption text that's why its not working now when use Base64 on both VI and encrypted text then its works fine now thank you so much

Comment: write this in answer so that i accept it

Answer (score 3):

now Its Works

```
 private fun encryptedKey (KEY_NAME: String, value: String){
    val keyGenerator : KeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
        KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
        "AndroidKeyStore"
    )

 
    val keyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        "alies",
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
    )
        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
        .build()


    keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
    val  secretKey: SecretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey()

    val  cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

    val iv = cipher.getIV();
    val encryption = cipher.doFinal(value.toByteArray())

    val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPrefs.edit()
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME+"EN", Base64.encodeToString(encryption,Base64.DEFAULT))
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME+"IV", Base64.encodeToString(iv,Base64.DEFAULT))
    editor.commit()

}

private fun decryptKey (KEY_NAME: String): String?{

    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);

    val secretKeyEntry = keyStore
        .getEntry("alies", null) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry

    val secretKey2 = secretKeyEntry.secretKey

    val cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
    val spec = GCMParameterSpec(128,Base64.decode(sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_NAME+"IV",null),Base64.DEFAULT))
    cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey2, spec)


    val decodedData = cipher2.doFinal(Base64.decode(sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_NAME+"EN",null),Base64.DEFAULT))
    val unencryptedString = String(decodedData)
    return unencryptedString
}
```